# Protractor / angular 2 control flow

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

i'm currently learning to write tests using protractor and i'm stuck and unable to understand the proper way to write a simple login/logout test.

```
 describe('Login with dummy user', function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get('https://localhost:44311');
    element(by.id('userNameInput')).sendKeys('blabla');
    element(by.id('passwordInput')).sendKeys('blablapassword');
    element(by.id('submitButton')).click();
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    browser.sleep(2000);

    it('page should have Inventory title', function () {
        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Inventory');
    });

    it(' page should have logout button', function () {
        var completedAmount = element.all(by.css('.logoutButton'));
        expect(completedAmount.count()).toEqual(1);
    });

    describe('clicking loging out button', function () {
        browser.sleep(2000);
        element(by.css('[href="/account/signout"]')).click();

        it('should redirect to account page', function () {
            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('https://localhost:44311/account');
        });

        it('should display a signed out message', function () {
            expect(element(by.css('text-success')).getText()).toEqual('You have successfully signed out');
        });
    });
});
```

I expect that the first two it would run before the second describe, but the browser clicks the button, logouts, browser closes and only then do the tests run and fail.

Comment: Keep all your code relevant to `it` inside your `it`. You can't keep anything outside `it` blocks, so move `element(by.id('userNameInput')).sendKeys('blabla');` and other to your `it`

Comment: But then how could i test 2 things? Or i am forced to have multiple expects in 1 it, instead of having multiple it?

Comment: You can make functions and keep repeated code inside the function, but each `it` should test what it has in its description. If you have to make couple of expects, you can.

Comment: You should look into `Page Object Pattern` for protractor. It really helps.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.protractortest.org/#/page-objects

Comment: So after putting the code inside the it, i'm getting this after the logout Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.getAllAngularTestabilities is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to keep all code inside 'it' blocks and keep the Login & LogOut functionality inside the "beforeAll" and "afterAll" functions respectively as below:

```
describe('Login with dummy user', function () {
   beforeAll(function() {
    // Login Steps
    // ignore synchronization set to true should have nested then statements
    // since the synchronization is removed. Example:
    // 
    // element(by.id('userNameInput')).sendKeys('blabla').then(() => {
    //   element(by.id('passwordInput')).sendKeys('blablapassword').then(() => {
    //     element(by.id('submitButton')).click();
    //   });
    // });
   });



    it('page should have Inventory title', function () {
        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Inventory');
    });

    it(' page should have logout button', function () {
        var completedAmount = element.all(by.css('.logoutButton'));
        expect(completedAmount.count()).toEqual(1);
    });



  afterAll(function() {
   //Logout steps
  });

});
```